# show that the limits does not exist (multivariable)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So my professor give me this problem

Show that the limit does not exist
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {xy^3\cos x}{2x^2+y^6}$$
So what I ended up doing is approach $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {0}{2x^2} = 0$$
and approach  $(0,0)$ along the $y$-axis
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac {0}{y^6} = 0.$$
Then I approach the $(0,0)$ along $y = x$ axis
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {x^2\cos x}{2+x^4} = 0$$
And so I thought the limit does exist, but my professor insists that the limit does not exist. Did I do something wrong ?

Thank you.

*sorry i wrote the wrong problem

Comment: i mistyped the problem, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {xy^3\cos x}{2x^2+y^6}$$
Try $x=y^3$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {y^6\cos y^3}{3y^6}$$
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {\cos y^3}{3}=\dfrac 13 \ne 0$$
Along the axis it gives zero so that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Why can you remove $2x^2$ in the denominator?

Comment: because $x^2=y^6$ it didnt disapear @Bernard

Comment: Oh! I misread. Yes, of course.

Comment: No problem @Bernard. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Approaching from the $x$-axis (when $y=0$) we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\cos(x)}{2x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

and approaching from the $y$-axis (when $x=0$) gives $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{y^6}=0.$$

Thus the limit does not exist.

---

Along the curve $y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2\cos(x)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{3}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: sorry i misstyped the problem

Comment: I've added above.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos x \to 1$ we can consider $ \frac {xy^3}{2x^2+y^6}$ and equating the exponents at the denominator by $x=u^3$ and $y=u$ we obtain

$$ \frac {xy^3}{2x^2+y^6}= \frac {u^6}{3u^6} \to \frac13$$